# Any way to connect to 2015 MacBook Air Toshiba SSD externally?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery

My sister recently started having issues with her early 2015 MacBook Air 11" (A1465). She took it in to an Authorized Apple Service Provider and they told her that it appeared to be liquid damage and the repair would most likely be above $300. She has decided to just upgrade to a new MacBook instead of paying for the repairs on this one.

I told her that I could most likely get all of the data off of her hard drive so that she wouldn't lose everything. I did some research and found [this adapter on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N9OUT8K) that seemed like it would work.

The adapter came in today and unfortunately it's not working for me. It does not recognize the SSD and so I am not able to recover anything. I did some more digging around and noticed that a lot of the adapters for this SSD do not support the SSD if it's a Toshiba drive. They support them if they are Samsung or SanDisk. And, well, as luck would have it, this SSD happens to be a Toshiba.

Now I'm at a loss on what to do. I'm not entirely convinced the SSD is toast  right now but I don't have any proof for it not to be. (Although my sister does not recall ever spilling liquid on her MacBook)

Has anyone run into this exact issue before? Or are there any suggestions on how to go about possibly recovering the data from this drive?

Comment: I'd try this [enclosure](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENPRPCI/). If the SSD is still working you can simply attach it to your sister's MB via USB and copy all data.

Comment: @klanomath Yeah I saw that enclosure but the fine print at the bottom says `Please Note: The OWC Envoy Pro enclosure is not compatible with stock Apple Toshiba drives`. I'm afraid that I'll spend the money on it only to find out it doesn't work with this specific SSD.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this one... sorry!

Comment: No worries! It took me a while to see it as well lol I almost bought it.